# Regex help for NOT expression

Tags: java, regex

I need a regular expression in java that does the following,

Match a pattern that is **NOT** the following

- An optional negative sign ( '-' ) Followed by
- One to four numbers Followed by
- An optional dot character Followed by
- one or many zeroes ( If there is a dot )

```
(?!-{0,1}\\d{1,4}\\.{0,1}0{1,4})
```

The behavior is below

Expression finds a match for 1
Expression does not find a match for 1.0

when it cones to regex it some times results in a simpler solution if i ask what i need to accomplish as opposed to questions about inner workings.

In my case

I want to catch an decimal number pattern but anything like 1.000 is fine but 1.0001 is not

Some examples

```
1           No match
1234        No match
99          No Match
1.000000    No match
123.000000  No Match
-123        No Match

1.01        Match
-1.1        Match
12345566    Match
```

Comment: If you'd really like some help, you'd post about 10 lines to test against, including those you do and don't want matches for. ;-)

Comment: I was with you until 12345566, why would that match when no other integer matches?

Comment: Because the number of digits is more than 4

Comment: Can we basically presume you want to validate numbers to be under a range, or are throttled by a specific number of sig-figs? This is starting to feel like a math problem from that really eccentric teacher that even the staff don't talk to.

Comment: Seems to me that you have a pretty good idea what *not* to match. Why not use a regex for *that* and reverse the condition in your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^-?\d{1,4}(\.0+)?$
```

You need to use the program itself to reject input. Perhaps match valid numbers, then reject anything that matches this, then return.

Comment: This worked. Hail regex guru. can you please tell me what the difference is between what you have done and what i have done.

Comment: Whoops, missed an escape. What I did that you didn't do was to group the decimal separator with the numbers that follow it.

Answer (score 0):

`((-)?(\d){1,4}+(\.)?(0)*([1-9]+))`

This seems to match your examples, but I'm still not sure what you're trying to accomplish with this.

Comment: I was more thinking `(-?\d{1,4}(?:\.\d{1,4}))` but then it's basically a negative look-ahead.

Comment: @Brad The thing that's really throwing me off is "one or many zeros (if there is a dot)" seems to contradict -1.1 being a match.

Comment: @Shaded: I'm really just confused all-around. To me it seems more plausible to find the numbers you *don't* want, then negate the result. i.e. `if (!isMatch)...` rather than putting the reverse logic in the expression.

Comment: @Staffan Haaaa yeah, that would be a good idea wouldn't it :P

Comment: IMO, it's too bloated with all those unnecessary parenthesis. They can all be removed and the regex will match exactly the same.

Comment: Ok, Here is why i need it for. The record field in a file has to be a number(positive is implied and negative will have a '-' as prefix ) that is one to 4 digits long integer, however the record can append any number of decimals as long as the digits after the decimals are zeroes. I need the regex to capture records that dont adhere to the above condition. Hope that clears it a little bit.